# Showing a modal dialog with jquery ui without an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm making a small jquery application. I need some confirmation boxes to appear. However, I don't want to have to append an element to the body just so I can open up a dialog box. Is there a way to avoid this? To just call a dialog and pass arguments such as the title and text and options?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create a jQuery UI dialog box, current versions (1.8.*) *automatically* add the dialog to the body.

So if you do:

```
$('<div>').dialog({modal: true})
```

it just works.  You should ensure that you call`.remove()` with the dialog is closed to remove the new element, though!

```
function myalert(title, text) {
    var div = $('<div>').html(text).dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }}]
    })
};

myalert("Test", "This is a test modal dialog");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/G3GRZ/ for full working demo.

Answer (score 5):

Just do it:

```
$('<div>My dialog text.</div>').dialog({ modal: true });
```